# What is the purpose of some fields in Elasticsearch documents to have @ and _ at the beginning and some duplicates

Tags: elasticsearch

Why some fields of *document* of *Elasticsearch* have at the beginning the characters "@" and "_" and duplicated eg:

> @ at the beginning: `@tags, @type`
> _ at the beginning: `_score, _type`

Some fields have *two versions* one with "@" and the other with "_" (with the same value):

> `@version and _version`

Some fields have *two versions* one with "@" and the other without:

> `fields(inside root) and @fields(inside _source)`

Some fields are duplicated (and with the same value):

> `@timestamp(inside fields) and @timestamp(inside _source)`

Below is a real *document* of *Elasticsearch* with these fields:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2021.02.25",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "q9_C1ncBR7kZ5_B9FyW_",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "arquivo": "C:\\DEV_HOME\\GeradorDePlanilha.cs",
    "level": "INFO",
    "@tags": [],
    "@type": "amqp",
    "date": "2021-02-24 22:16:20.0910",
    "@version": "1",
    "type": "App.Log",
    "metodo": "GerarPlanilhaComDadosGerenciaisBasicosAsync",
    "@timestamp": "2021-02-25T01:16:20.091Z",
    "origin": "App.Api.Worker",
    "@fields": {},
    "@source": "nlog://DESKTOP-F8BDSSI/API.Gerencia.GeradorDePlanilha",
    "logger": "App.Log.Gerencia.GeradorDePlanilha",
    "@message": "Método: GerarPlanilhaComDadosGerenciaisBasicosAsync Arquivo: C:\\DEV_HOME\\GeradorDePlanilha.cs Linha: 33",
    "machineName": "DESKTOP-F8BDSSI"
  },
  "fields": {
    "metodoCompleto": [
      "GerarPlanilhaComDadosGerenciaisBasicosAsync - C:\\DEV_HOME\\GeradorDePlanilha.cs"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-02-25T01:16:20.091Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1614215780091
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`_fields` Are reserved fields for Elasticsearch used for meta-fields outside the document source (like _source, _score, _id, etc). This fields are system generated and standard for all documents.

`@fields` Have no special meaning on Elasticsearch but are used for meta-fields inside the document source. @timestamp is a convention standard for time based documents. This fields are not system generated nor standard for all documents.

You can use `_fields` inside the document source but you should prefer `@fields`. You can think on the underscore as a "system field" meaning.

For example on index names you can't start with `_`

About your document in particular, the `_fields` outside source were generated by elasticsearch and the ones inside source were generated by the Logstash conf file.